# Dúvida sobre o erro "Error converting data type varchar to float"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

> Error converting data type varchar to float

Este erro está ocorrendo quando realizo um `Update` em uma tabela, segue abaixo o código:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Notas SET nota = '" + nota.nota + "' WHERE idMateria = '" + nota.idMateria + "' and idAluno = '" + nota.idAluno + "';", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

O campo nota esta criado no BD como `float`, já tentei realizar a conversão porém não estou conseguindo, alguma dica?

Comment: Qual o valor de 'nota.nota' ?

Comment: O valor de `nota.nota` é do tipo `float` e é pego de um `input`

Comment: A resposta do @ciganoMorrisonMendez realmente é a melhor recomendada!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Edição**
>  *Atenção: Essa resposta pode deixar seu código vulnerável a
> SQL Injection, use [essa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102842/23192).*

Bem, vamos por partes...

- Em sua clausura `WHERE` você está usando aspas simples para campos que aparentemente são do tipo `int`, mas a grosso modo isso só deve ser feito em campos do tipo `varchar`.
- Conforme conversamos no chat da questão, aparentemente seu banco de dados está configurado no padrão `en-US` onde os valores reais são separados por **ponto** e não **vírgula** como aqui em nosso Brasilzão.

Apergunta é:
Que tipo de variável é `nota.nota`?
`string` ou `float`?

---

#### string

Neste caso você precisará fazer um [REPLACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186862(v=sql.120).aspx) em sua query substituindo a vírgula por ponto, e depois disso precisará também fazer um [CONVERT ou CAST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187928(v=sql.120).aspx) para que a `string` seja transformada magicamente em um valor do tipo `float`. Isso é necessário pois não é possível inserir uma `string` em um campo que foi criado para receber `float`.

A query ficaria assim:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Notas SET nota = CONVERT(FLOAT, REPLACE('" + nota.nota + "', ',', '.')) WHERE idMateria = " + nota.idMateria + " and idAluno = " + nota.idAluno + ";", con);
```

Ou ainda poderia fazer o [`replace` via C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) antes de criar a query:

```
nota.nota = nota.nota.Replace(",", ".");
```

E assim gerar a query sem o replace:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Notas SET nota = CONVERT(FLOAT, '" + nota.nota + "') WHERE idMateria = " + nota.idMateria + " and idAluno = " + nota.idAluno + ";", con);
```

Essas seriam as melhores opções? Ao meu ver não tem um cheirinho muito bom...
Em minha humilde opinião se `nota.nota` fosse do tipo `float` ficaria bem mais bonitinho.

---

#### float

Como o valor está chegando da `View`?
`string` ou `float`?

Se estiver chegando como string, [converta para `float` no `Controller`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/2thct5cb(v=vs.110).aspx), mas eu particularmente preferiria [converter para `float` na `View`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) já enviando assim o objeto prontinho.

Assim sua query ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Notas SET nota = " + nota.nota + " WHERE idMateria = " + nota.idMateria + " and idAluno = " + nota.idAluno + ";", con);
```

Comment: Fiz como descreveu porem ocorreu um novo erro  `Incorrect syntax near '5'.` (Obs.: Apenas o valor de nota é `float`)

Comment: os ids são `varchar`? que BD você está usando?

Comment: os ids são do tipo `int` o banco é Mysql Server 2014

Comment: Alterei a resposta, veja se agora te atende...

Comment: Alterei porem agora esta com este erro `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`

Comment: coloque um breakpoint nessa linha e verifique se o valor está vindo corretamente...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32706/discussion-between-jedaias-rodrigues-and-vinicius-vaz).

Answer (score 5):

Você precisa usar parâmetros:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE Notas 
                           SET nota = @nota 
                           WHERE idMateria = @idMateria 
                           and idAluno = @idAluno", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@nota", SqlDbType.Float).Value = nota.nota;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@idMateria", SqlDbType.Int).Value = nota.idMateria;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@idAluno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = nota.idAluno;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Parâmetros resolvem pra você o tipo da variável, previnem *SQL Injection* e comportamentos estranhos na execução. [Veja mais aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ht4eset1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: A resposta que o @Jedaias Rodrigues me passou funcionou, `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Notas SET nota = " + nota.nota + " WHERE idMateria = " + nota.idMateria + " and idAluno = " + nota.idAluno + ";", con);` com este código estou vulnerável a SQL Injection?

Comment: Com certeza. De fato a resposta funciona, mas essa prática de montar SQL com variável livre precisa ser evitada. Não é este caso em específico, mas imagine que uma das propriedades de `nota` fosse *string*. Concorda comigo que posso escrever `drop database SeuBanco; `?